# SQL Server is blocking a database insert because of a Unique Key Contstraint, but the key IS unique

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following Unique Key Constraint on a database table:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Adviser] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [UQ__Adviser__C56B02E841AB1B87] 
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Code] ASC, [Name] ASC)
```

There is currently a row in the database with the code `DUFFENDI` and name `Dizzee Uffendi` and I'm trying to add a row with code `DUFFENDIBGL` and name `Dizzee Uffendi` but I get an error:

> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Adviser'

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error when the key IS unique?

Comment: Correct me if I be mistaken, but the error you are getting would seem to be caused by duplicate data which _already_ exists in your table.

Comment: What is the data type and column width of the `Code` and `Name` columns? Are you getting any data truncation warnings while inserting the row?

Comment: What other unique/primary key constraints and indexes are on the table?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Nope, definitely doesn't exist in the table

Comment: @Phylyp: Both columns are nvarchar(255), the only error I'm getting is Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Adviser'

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: The only other key is the primary key, an auto incrementing integer

Comment: Do you get this error when trying to create the unique constraint, or when trying to insert the data?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: When trying to insert the data.

Comment: The full error message should tell you both the constraint being violated and the values that are violating it, but how are you trying to insert the values? For example, if you're inserting them from variables, is the code variable nvarchar(8) (or less than 8)? If so, `DUFFENDI` will be the same as `DUFFENDIBGL` because it'll be trimmed to 8 (or less) characters. Note: If you are inserting them from variables and you haven't specified a length for the variables, they'll be trimmed to a single character.

Comment: @ZLK: I thought that may be the case but there are plenty of other Codes  in the table where the first 8 letters of the code are the same with a few characters concatenated on the end and the same Name value.

Comment: Right, but how you do the insert matters. For example, if you're inserting them like `DECLARE @code NVARCHAR(8) = N'DUFFENDIBGL', @name NVARCHAR(255) = N'Dizzee Uffendi'; INSERT dbo.Adviser(Code, Name) SELECT @code, @name;` you'll get an error message saying you're violating the key because `DUFFENDIBGL` will be trimmed to `DUFFENDI` in this instance. Maybe other instances were done properly. If, for example, you do what I wrote in the example but change it to `NVARCHAR(255)` instead of `NVARCHAR(8)`, you shouldn't see an error message.